# Android and Eclipse - what's going on?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, r.java-file

I am new to android programming although I've been programming embedded and win apps for a while. I have used Eclipse a little bit when doing some Linux programming.

So I use Eclipse to start a new project/activity. Everything works fine, I work out implementation, debug, great...

Then at some point (this has happened several times and I had to just start the entire project over) Eclipse wigs out and start throwing compile errors at me like crazy. Being new to Android, not many of the errors are too helpful but I am still baffled as to why the problem occurs all of a sudden.

I know at least twice the problem has happened after creating a new (2nd) activity screen in my project.

The largest group of errors references "R cannot be resolved to a variable" - in my MainActivity.java (which had 0 errors until the new activity was added).

2 examples
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      On = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

When I delete the new activity it appears the errors go away. Could anyone explain to a noob what is happening here and why? I am still having a hell of a time wrapping my head around all the special android terminology and classes.

Comment: Did you import android.R in any of the activities?. If so remove it. Do you have errors in any of the resource files?. If so fix it. Clean and build the project

Comment: Similarly, errors in the manifest can trigger this problem. If `R.java` is not being code-generated in your `gen/` directory, then a malformed resource or manifest entry is almost always the culprit.

Comment: Update, this time instead of using BLANK activity for my new screen, I used EMPTY. This hasn't created the same issues so far but when I attempt to drop a text input, I get: Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Comment: Thanks for the input so far, let me address these. I did not (knowingly) import R and it seems I would have to manually do so (ie - It doesn't occur at the creation of a new activity in Eclipse)Commons, what would cause the R not to be generated just because a new blank activity was added?

Answer (score 2):

First check whether R.java is present in gen folder or not.If not then there must be some error in your xml.
And if is not present, try cleaning the project.

Comment: yes, this is the best & quickest way to see WHY Eclipse is giving the errors.

Comment: How should a beginner detect errors in the xml files?

Answer (score 1):

Below actions might help you.

Sometimes errors in xml file cause R.java error. Try finding any such error.

Try cleaning the project.

Check your build path also, if required jars are there and not duplicated.

Comment: What errors in xml files, and how should a beginner recognise them?

Comment: If you are using an IDE like eclipse, in folder structure, xml file will get some asterisk mark. If you open that file error should be highlighted.